# Trying to populate POST data in a lightbox

Tags: asp.net, post, lightbox

I have a form on my master page and I am submitting the data using POST to another page .

```
<form id="Form2" action="index.aspx" method="post" name="Form2">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="form_right_top" runat="server">


        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<div id="page_form">
    <!-- sample error here -->
    <div style="color: red; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 110px; clear: both; padding-top: 6px;">
    </div>
    <!-- end sample error -->
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 30px;">
        First Name*</div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 148px; height: 30px;">
        <input type="text" tabindex="100" id="FIRST_NAME" maxlength="14" name="FIRST_NAME">
    </div>
    <div style="color: red; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 110px; clear: both; padding-top: 6px;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 30px;">
        Last Name*</div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 148px; height: 30px;">
        <input type="text" tabindex="101" id="LAST_NAME" maxlength="14" name="LAST_NAME">
    </div>
    <div style="color: red; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 110px; clear: both; padding-top: 6px;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 30px;">
        Billing Address*</div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 148px; height: 30px;">
        <input type="text" tabindex="102" id="ADDRESS" maxlength="30" name="ADDRESS"></div>

    <div style="color: red; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 110px; clear: both; padding-top: 6px;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 30px;">
        City*</div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 148px; height: 30px;">
        <input type="text" tabindex="104" id="CITY" maxlength="18" name="CITY"></div>
    <div style="color: red; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 110px; clear: both; padding-top: 6px;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 30px;">
        State*
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 148px; height: 30px;">
        <select style="width: 145px;" size="1" tabindex="105" id='STATE' name='STATE' >
            <option value="AK">AK</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option>
            <option value="AR">AR</option>
            <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
            <option value="CA">CA</option>
            <option value="CO">CO</option>
            <option value="CT">CT</option>
            <option value="DE">DE</option>
            <option value="DC">DC</option>
            <option value="FL">FL</option>
            <option value="GA">GA</option>
            <option value="HI">HI</option>
            <option value="IA">IA</option>
            <option value="ID">ID</option>
            <option value="IL">IL</option>
            <option value="IN">IN</option>
            <option value="KS">KS</option>
            <option value="KY">KY</option>
            <option value="LA">LA</option>
            <option value="MA">MA</option>
            <option value="MD">MD</option>
            <option value="ME">ME</option>
            <option value="MI">MI</option>
            <option value="MN">MN</option>
            <option value="MO">MO</option>
            <option value="MS">MS</option>
            <option value="MT">MT</option>
            <option value="NC">NC</option>
            <option value="ND">ND</option>
            <option value="NE">NE</option>
            <option value="NH">NH</option>
            <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
            <option value="NM">NM</option>
            <option value="NV">NV</option>
            <option value="NY">NY</option>
            <option value="OH">OH</option>
            <option value="OK">OK</option>
            <option value="OR">OR</option>
            <option value="PA">PA</option>
            <option value="RI">RI</option>
            <option value="SC">SC</option>
            <option value="SD">SD</option>
            <option value="TN">TN</option>
            <option value="TX">TX</option>
            <option value="UT">UT</option>
            <option value="VA">VA</option>
            <option value="VT">VT</option>
            <option value="WA">WA</option>
            <option value="WI">WI</option>
            <option value="WV">WV</option>
            <option value="WY">WY</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="color: red; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 110px; clear: both; padding-top: 6px;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 30px;">
        Zip Code*</div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 148px; height: 30px;">
        <input type="text" tabindex="106" id="POSTAL_CODE" name="POSTAL_CODE"></div>
    <div style="color: red; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 110px; clear: both; padding-top: 6px;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 30px;">
        Phone*</div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 148px; height: 30px;">
        <input type="text" tabindex="107" id="Form1_TextBoxPhone" maxlength="15" name="Form1$TextBoxPhone"></div>
    <div style="color: red; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 110px; clear: both; padding-top: 6px;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 30px;">
        E-mail Address*</div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 148px; height: 30px;">
        <input type="text" tabindex="110" id="EMAIL" name="EMAIL_ADDRESS"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both">
    </div>

    <div style="position: relative; width: 270px; height: 53px; text-align: center;">
     <input type="image" style="border-width: 0px;" src="images/form_ordernow_btn.jpg"
            tabindex="129" id="Form1_ImageButton1" name="Form1$ImageButton1"  >

    </div>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Return_shipping" runat="server">


        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</div>
```

When I just submit it by using an ordinary submit button a shown in the code ,the data gets passed on the redirected page and I am able to view it on the screen by using the below code in the index.aspx page

```
    <table>
<tr>
<td><% Response.Write(Page.Request.Form["FIRST_NAME"]); %></td>
<td><% Response.Write(Page.Request.Form["LAST_NAME"]); %></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

However the requirement is that I display this page in a lightbox which pops open when I hit the submit on the form .However if I change the code for the submit to the form to this :

```
<a href="index.aspx?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="New form page"> <input type="image" style="border-width: 0px;" src="images/form_ordernow_btn.jpg"
            tabindex="129" id="Form1_ImageButton1" name="Form1$ImageButton1"  ></a>
```

None of the Post values are getting passed through .I am not sure,but I guess the lighbox is overriding the Post back and hence I am just getting an empty page which pops up when I click the button ,but the question is how do I pass these POST values while using a lightbox

Thanks